# Padding not disappearing when it is set to 0 at certain breakpoint

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design

I have padding set on a div for the main text on my pages, but have it set to disappear at 700px with a media query. For some reason, it's not working and I don't know why. Below is a code pen and my code. Thank you!

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/EgWzgz

```css
#contentOne {
  height: 100%;
  /*** change to 100% once all is put in ***/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4484CE;
  z-index: 1;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #4484CE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
#gray {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*** change to 100% once all is put in ***/
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
}
#title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 114px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
#text {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 114px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 98px;
  height: 100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
  #text {
    padding-left: none;
    padding-right: none;
  }
  #title {
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="contentOne">
    <div id="blue">
      <!-- this is blue for navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- end blue -->
    <div id="gray">
      <!-- this is gray for main/content one -->
      <div id="title">Attendance Office</div>
      <div id="text">
        <p><strong>(323)993-3408</strong>
        </p>
        <p><strong>The Attendance Office is open from 7:00am to 3:30 pm.</strong> We are here to help you with absences, contact information update, enrollment, check-outs, etc.<strong> </strong>
        </p>
        <p>Attendance at school is extremely important. By state law, a student who has more than 3 unexcused absences is determined to be in violation of the truancy laws.</p>
        <p>The following is a listing of the only reasons that are excusable:</p>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>Due to his or her illness</li>
          <li>Due to quarantine under the direction of a county or cit health officer</li>
          <li>For the purpose of having medical, dental, optometric or chiropractic services rendered</li>
          <li>For the purpose of attending the funeral services of a member of his or her immediate family</li>
          <li>For the purpose of jury duty in the manner provided by law</li>
          <li>Due to the illness or medical appointment during school hours of a child whom the pupil is the custodial parent</li>
          <li>With Prior Principal Approval, for justifiable personal reasons including, but not limited to, an appearance in court, attendance at a funeral service past the allowable day(s), observance of a holiday or ceremony of his/her religion, attendance
            at religious retreats or attendance at an employment conference when the pupil's absence has been requested in writing, prior to the absence, by the parent/guardian and approved by the principal.</li>
          <li>With Prior Principal Approval, for the purpose of serving as a member of a precinct board for an election pursuant to Section 12302 of the Election Code.</li>
          <li>Pupils who are members of religions that observe religious holidays that fall on school days may be excusable from school by making prior arrangements, as specified by the school principal and with written parental/guardian request.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>PLEASE NOTE THAT THE ABOVE REASONS ARE THE ONLY REASONS THAT WILL <u>NOT</u> TRIGGER A TRUANCY LETTER. </strong> 
        </p>
        <p><strong>BELOW ARE SOME EXAMPLES OF UNEXCUSED ABSENCES: </strong>
        </p>
        <p>Three or more of the following excuses will trigger a Truancy letter:</p>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>Running errands for family</li>
          <li>Vacations or trips</li>
          <li>Unverified illness</li>
          <li>Family emergency</li>
          <li>Transportation problems</li>
          <li>Inclement weather</li>
          <li>Babysitting</li>
          <li>Absent from class without school or parent/guardian permission</li>
          <li>Absence uncleared for more than 10 school days despite due diligence efforts to obtain an explanation from the parent/guardian</li>
          <li>Unexcused tardy for 30 minutes or more</li>
          <li>No note from parent/guardian</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Leaving School Early:</strong> 
          <br />
          <br />Students upon arriving on campus are not to leave school for any reason without permission. Students needing to leave early must be picked up by a parent/guardian/adult that is on the emergency card. Only those listed in the emergency card are
          able to pick up students out of school and <u>must present a picture ID every time</u>.
          <br />
          <br />
          <strong>To Enroll a Student in Bancroft Middle School:</strong>
          <br />
          <br />You will need the following items completed prior to registration:
          <br />Last report card
          <br />Parent/guardian picture ID
          <br />Birth certificate
          <br />Immunization records (must be up to date)
          <br />Address verification (Utility bill, Gas, Water, or Light only) in Parent's name. (You cannot use telephone bill)
          <br />
          <br />
          <strong>PARENTS/GUARDIANS ARE REQUIRED TO REPORT TO THE ATTENDANCE OFFICE, IN WRITING, A CHANGE OF ADDRESS OR CONTACT INFORMATION WITHIN 30 CALENDAR DAYS OF THE CHANGE. PROOF OF THIS CHANGE IS ALSO REQUIRED. FAILURE TO DO SO MAY BE CAUSE FOR FORFEITURE OF THE RIGHT TO A CONTINUING ENROLLMENT PERMIT. STUDENTS WILL BE TRANSFERRED TO THE SCHOOL OF RESIDENCE IF FALSE OR INACCURATE RESIDENCE INFORMATION IS DISCOVERED.</strong>
        </p>
        <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong><a href="attendance_policy.html">Click here for the Attendance Policy</a>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>La oficina de asistencia está abierta está abierta de 7:00am a 3:30 pm.</strong> Estamos aquí para servirle con respecto a ausencias, actualización de información de emergencia, inscripciones, dadas de baja, etc.<strong> </strong>
        </p>
        <p>Asistencia a clases es extremadamente importante. Por las leyes del estado un estudiante que tiene más de 3 ausencias sin excusa es considerada una violación de las leyes de asistencia.
          <br />&nbsp;La siguiente lista provee las únicas razones para ausencia excusada:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Enfermedad o lesión del alumno</li>
          <li>Cuarentena</li>
          <li>Servicios médicos, dentales, oftalmológicos o quiroprácticos</li>
          <li>Asistencia a funeral de un miembro de la familia directo, P.ej. madre, padre, abuelo, abuela, hermano, hermana, o cualquier familiar que viva en el mismo domicilio que el alumno (un día si es en el Estado, tres días fuera del Estado)</li>
          <li>Obligación de jurado</li>
          <li>Enfermedad o tratamiento médico de un niño cuya patria potestad sea del alumno.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Las Razones Personales Justificables de una ausencia son aquellas que se presentan por escrito, por parte del padre de familia, y <u>son aprobadas por el director</u>. Las ausencias que encuadran en esta categoría, incluyen entre otras:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Servicio militar activo en zona de combate (miembro directo de la familia -máximo tres días)</li>
          <li>Comparecencia en un tribunal o Asistencia a servicios funerarios (extensión de días)</li>
          <li>Asistencia a un retiro religioso (que no exceda cuatro horas por semestre)</li>
          <li>Industria del entretenimiento (no más de cinco días de ausencia consecutiva o un máximo de cinco ausencias por año escolar)</li>
          <li>Exclusión o exención médica</li>
          <li>Conmemoración religiosa, feriado cultural, ceremonia y secular histórica.</li>
          <li>Instrucción religiosa (asistir a jornada escolar mínima no más de cuatro días por mes escolar)</li>
          <li>Suspensión revocada mediante el proceso de apelaciones</li>
          <li>Participación en una organización no lucrativa de artes escénicas (máximo cinco por año escolar)</li>
          <li>Servicios de salud mental previamente coordinados (Tratamiento Diurno de Salud Mental)</li>
          <li>&ldquo;Día de Llevar a Nuestros Hijos e Hijas a la Escuela ®&rdquo;</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>POR FAVOR NOTE QUE LAS RAZONES MECIONADAS ARRIBA SON LAS UNICAS RAZONES QUE <u>NO</u> CREARAN UNA CARTA DE AUSENCIAS INJUSTIFICADAS. </strong>
        </p>
        <p><strong>ABAJO ESTA LA LISTA DE EJEMPLOS DE AUSENCIAS NO JUSTIFICADAS: </strong>
        </p>
        <p>Tres o más de este tipo de ausencias hará una carta de ausencias no excusadas:</p>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>Hacer diligencias para el padre/tutor</li>
          <li>Vacaciones o viajes</li>
          <li>Enfermedades sin verificación</li>
          <li>Problema de transporte</li>
          <li>Inclemencias del clina</li>
          <li>Cuidar de niños menores</li>
          <li>Ausencia a clase sin permiso de la escuela o padre/tutor</li>
          <li>Ausencia sin nota de padre/tutor</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Salir temprano de la escuela:</strong> 
          <br />
          <br />Ya que los estudiantes entran a la escuela no pueden salir por ninguna razón sin permiso de la escuela. Los estudiantes que necesiten salir temprano deberán ser recogidos por un padre/tutor/adulto que este listado en la tarjeta de emergencia.
          Solamente aquellos listados en la tarjeta de emergencia podrán pasar por el estudiante y <u>deben presentar identificación fon fotografía cada vez</u> que vengan por el estudiante.
          <br />
          <br />
          <strong>Para inscribir a un estudiante a Bancroft Middle School:</strong>
          <br />
          <br />Usted tendrá que presentar los siguientes documentos antes de inscripción:
          <br />Última boleta de calificaciones
          <br />Identificación con fotografía del padre/tutor
          <br />Certificado de nacimiento
          <br />Cartilla de vacunas (actualizada)
          <br />Comprobante de domicilio (factura de gas, agua o luz solamente) en el nombre del padre/tutor. (No se aceptan facturas de teléfono)
          <br />
          <br />
          <strong>ES REQUERIDO QUE LOS PADRES/TUTORES REPORTEN POR ESCRITO A LA OFICINA DE ASISTENCIA CUANQUIER CAMBIO DE DIRECCION O CONTACTO DENTRO DE LOS 30 DIAS DEL CAMBIO. COMPROBANTE DE DOMICILIO ES REQUERIDO. EL NO HACER ESTO PUEDE CAUSAR LA PERDIDA DE ESPACIO EN LA ESCUELA Y EL ESTUDIANTE SERA TRANSFERIDO A SU ESCUELA DE RESIDENCIA SI SE NCUENTRA QUE LA INFORMACION PROVEEIDA ES FALSA O INCORRECTA.</strong>
        </p>
        <p><a href="attendance_policy.html">Clic aquí para la política de asistencia</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end text-->
    </div>
    <!-- end gray -->
  </div>
  <!-- end content one -->
</div>
<!-- end main -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`none` is not a valid value for `padding`.

```
#text{
    padding-left: none;
    padding-right: none;
}
```

Should be:

```
#text{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```